# How can I set a css property to tags with specific attribute?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change font of Inbox.google.com using extension like [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) but I only want change fonts in tag with attribue: dir="rtl" like this:

```
<div dir="rtl">سلام به همگی</div>
```

It only changes font of  rtl languages text, I Know it is possible by jquery but I don't how can I do this with css or any extension the run jquery on other webpages.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Attribute Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for CSS

```
div[dir="rtl"] {
  font-family: "Your Font";
}
```

Comment: I didn't know anything about attribute selector!
It's great!